# Problem with gam and mgcv packages: invalid type (list) for variable 'ti(LOC_X)'

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, gam, mgcv

I have the following data frame in R (heavily truncated, obviously):

```
    X PLAYER_ID  PLAYER_NAME LOC_X LOC_Y SHOT_MADE_FLAG
1     0    201935 James Harden    14    55              0
2     1    201935 James Harden     0    24              0
3     2    201935 James Harden    50    74              0
4     3    201935 James Harden   160   215              0
5     4    201935 James Harden    22    21              1
6     5    201935 James Harden   -43   278              1
7     6    201935 James Harden   221     6              0
8     7    201935 James Harden   -27    21              0
9     8    201935 James Harden  -119   235              0
10    9    201935 James Harden  -223   101              0
```

I named this data frame `shots` in R, and then tried the following:

```
league_model_19 <- gam(SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ ti(LOC_X) +
                         ti(LOC_Y) +
                         ti(LOC_X, LOC_Y),
                       data = shots)
```

But this gives the error shown in the title:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ ti(LOC_X) + ti(LOC_Y) +  :    invalid type (list) for variable 'ti(LOC_X)'

I checked the type of each value in `LOC_X`, and all of them are integers. I understand the column itself is a list/series, but shouldn't this work anyways?

Any way to avoid getting an error here would be great. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

`str(shots)` outputs:

```
> str(shots)
'data.frame':   1456 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ X             : int  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ PLAYER_ID     : int  201935 201935 201935 201935 201935 201935 201935 201935 201935 201935 ...
 $ PLAYER_NAME   : chr  "James Harden" "James Harden" "James Harden" "James Harden" ...
 $ LOC_X         : int  14 0 50 160 22 -43 221 -27 -119 -223 ...
 $ LOC_Y         : int  55 24 74 215 21 278 6 21 235 101 ...
 $ SHOT_MADE_FLAG: int  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 ...
```

and `dput(shots)` outputs (truncated):

```
> dput(shots)
structure(list(X = 0:1455, PLAYER_ID = c(201935L, 201935L, 201935L, 
201935L, 201935L, 201935L, 201935L, 201935L,....)
```

Edit 2:

```
> shots[c('LOC_X','LOC_Y','SHOT_MADE_FLAG')]
    LOC_X LOC_Y SHOT_MADE_FLAG
1      14    55              0
2       0    24              0
3      50    74              0
4     160   215              0
5      22    21              1
6     -43   278              1
7     221     6              0
8     -27    21              0
9    -119   235              0
10   -223   101              0
11     60   238              0
12    232    74              0
13   -136   239              0
14    -14     7              1
15    192   168              0
16    157   206              0
17    172   189              0
18   -168   194              0
19     10     4              1
20     -5    10              0
21   -127   228              0
22    -63   259              0
23    -95   241              1
24    227    27              0
25    -12    12              1
26    192   160              0
27   -144   236              0
28      6   281              0
29     40   250              1
30     29    52              0
31   -120   224              0
32      3    10              1
33   -131   221              0
34     32   276              0
35    -18    10              1
36     30   258              0
37    -31   251              0
38    141   210              0
39     13    77              0
40     -6    19              1
41    -18    62              0
42     47   140              0
43    210   132              0
44    139   217              0
45    163   196              1
46    -30    16              1
47     27   256              1
48   -195   173              0
49      0   251              0
50      2    22              1
51    157   203              0
52     54   249              0
53   -132   233              0
54     20     1              1
55    197   210              0
56   -147   224              1
57      1    29              1
58    -31    22              0
59   -128   236              0
60    -35    13              0
61    -29    14              1
62    234    89              0
63    196   172              0
64   -149   220              0
65     94   252              1
66    -92   269              0
67     14    20              1
68     -6    17              1
69   -171   190              1
70    163   205              0
71      2     4              1
72     11    14              1
73    117   256              0
74      0    35              0
75     -3     0              1
76   -232   120              0
77     -8     7              1
78     -2   298              1
79     -6    16              1
80    135   243              1
81      4    17              0
82    149   222              0
83     -6    31              1
84    122    97              1
85    -27    15              1
86     -2    34              0
87   -179   227              1
88      0    17              1
89    -55   310              0
90    223   159              0
91      3    -1              1
92    -11    17              0
93    -78   247              1
94     19    20              0
95     -9    16              0
96    -44   248              0
97    122   220              0
98    -15    -2              0
99      0     5              1
100   101   237              0
101   237    17              0
102   -32   250              1
103    -5    11              1
104   109   216              0
105  -228    45              0
106    18    29              1
107   -25    11              1
108   128   117              1
109   -38   246              0
110    39    57              0
111  -111   284              0
112   -44    83              0
113   111   223              0
114   -14   101              1
115     2    86              0
116    90   232              0
117    98   228              0
118     0    34              1
119     8    57              0
120   130   209              0
121    81   244              1
122     5    15              1
123   -18    27              0
124    -6    17              0
125   210   122              0
126   199   149              0
127   120   221              0
128  -142   221              0
129   -11    12              0
130   226    60              1
131  -152   212              0
132  -188   181              0
133    -1     4              1
134   -22   253              0
135   -16   253              0
136    -6    23              1
137  -120   275              1
138     8    52              1
139   -15     8              0
140  -237     8              1
141   190   159              0
142     9     8              0
143   -50    74              0
144   -17    17              0
145  -143   231              0
146  -136   222              1
147   200   147              1
148  -176   186              1
149  -229    48              0
150   -16    17              1
151   -65    11              0
152   -54    89              0
153     6    16              1
154    -9     8              0
155   -11     2              1
156   -94   251              0
157  -141   246              1
158    45   239              0
159   230    82              1
160     7     4              0
161   -16    13              1
162   131   227              1
163   125   235              0
164    20   260              0
165   -46   252              0
166   144   211              0
167    -2     4              1
168   104   253              1
169     8    16              0
170   109   226              0
171    -1    71              1
172  -201   147              0
173    76   241              0
174     0     2              1
175    21    52              0
176   -79    16              0
177  -196   157              0
178   168   194              1
179  -131   236              1
180     2     6              1
181    42   254              1
182   -50   262              1
183    -6     0              1
184    57   278              0
185   229    14              1
186   127   226              1
187   139   230              0
188  -234   111              0
189   157   211              0
190    82   255              0
191  -216   138              0
192   230   101              0
193    14     2              0
194   -47   252              0
195   -12    10              1
196   113   231              0
197   -28   264              1
198     2   248              0
199   -17     4              1
200  -235    13              1
201    48   253              1
202    20   256              0
203    -1    18              0
204  -109   233              0
205  -107   238              0
206  -116    14              0
207    14    57              0
208    63   240              1
209    96   246              0
210    13    47              0
211  -188   172              1
212    24   252              1
213   123   257              1
214  -144   206              0
215    11    61              1
216    77   247              1
217   158   201              1
218   107   315              0
219    11   283              0
220   161   209              0
221     1    45              0
222  -105   225              0
223     9    30              1
224    27    -6              1
225     3    58              1
226   -19     3              0
227  -165   208              0
228     3    55              1
229  -176   201              1
230   -18    11              0
231   -13    78              1
232   -16     7              1
233   -27   254              0
234  -117   263              0
235    95   233              0
236   211   146              0
237    -6    46              1
238     3    20              1
239   -22    79              1
240    -8   270              1
241   161   190              1
242    20    70              0
243   -14    10              1
244   144   249              1
245    14     0              1
246   -22    29              1
247     8    53              0
248     4   104              0
249   236    15              0
250   113   222              1
251   -40   260              1
252    51   115              0
253  -181   178              0
254  -144   218              0
255    62    49              0
256   116   257              1
257   131   237              1
258    38    81              1
259    -6   114              1
260   -21    21              0
261   111   266              0
262   -36    14              0
263   103   272              0
264   -27    41              0
265     3    80              0
266   -20    17              1
267   -44   316              1
268   152   253              0
269   -65   255              1
270    76   243              1
271   -35   284              0
272     5    69              1
273  -114   249              0
274    32   127              0
275   192   172              1
276  -159   205              0
277     0    13              0
278   200   155              0
279    11    10              0
280   -11    38              1
281   -98   256              1
282    87   239              0
283   -88   259              1
284     8    71              0
285     1     8              1
286    -6    82              1
287   -27    55              1
288   -14   267              0
289     0   262              0
290   -36    69              1
291   -11    59              1
292  -177   271              1
293   -62   277              1
294    -4    21              0
295    84   243              0
296   -47    48              1
297   -36    48              0
298   -94   236              0
299    -6    20              0
300    -1    34              0
301   -88   251              1
302     2    11              0
303  -225    29              0
304   -25    31              0
305     3    76              1
306   -16    31              1
307   -36   262              1
308  -164   221              0
309     5    21              0
310    -1    11              1
311    -1   264              1
312     6   260              0
313     0    28              0
314   -98   239              0
315    -6    91              1
316   -98   251              0
317    85   244              1
318   -51   273              0
319    14    24              0
320    -9    21              0
321    57   253              1
322    50   251              1
323  -231     1              0
324    -5    15              1
325  -143   214              0
326   -51   248              0
327   147   219              0
328    39   258              0
329    92   150              0
330    72   282              0
331     0    -1              0
332    13    32              1
333   -22   258              1
```

Comment: I can't replicate this with `set.seed(101); shots <- data.frame(SHOT_MADE_FLAG=rbinom(200,size=1,prob=0.5), LOC_X=rnorm(200),LOC_Y=rnorm(200))`.  Can we see `str(shots)` and/or have a [mcve]?

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem with your data head because of `Model has more coefficients than data`. Can you `dput(shots)` and paste it in your question
?

Comment: I *can* replicate if I additionally use `shots$LOC_X <- list(shots$LOC_X)`. It seems as though you have internal structure in your data frame that's making `ti()` unhappy.  What happens if you do `shots$LOC_X <- unlist(shots$LOC_X)` ?

Comment: @BenBolker unfortunately the same error persists even if I unlist. I'm super inexperienced in R so I'm unsure of other workarounds. I also added dput(shots)

Comment: @BenNorris added them. Looks okay to me, but I rarely use R.

Comment: @lowlyprogrammer - In order for me to try to reproduce your problem, I need more of your data. Your `dput()` only has the first two variables...

Comment: I pretty sure you have another package loaded after *mgcv* that is masking the `ti()` function. I'm sure there is another question on here asking the same thing, and recall it might be a particular time series package that exports a `ti()`. If you show the output from `sessionInfo()` I can probably confirm this is the issue

Answer (score 0):

So far I still can't replicate this. This should be a comment but is a bit too long.

Read in the data you've provided:

```
shots <- read.csv(text=
"X,PLAYER_ID,PLAYER_NAME,LOC_X,LOC_Y,SHOT_MADE_FLAG
0,201935,James Harden,14,55,0
1,201935,James Harden,0,24,0
2,201935,James Harden,50,74,0
3,201935,James Harden,160,215,0
4,201935,James Harden,22,21,1
5,201935,James Harden,-43,278,1
6,201935,James Harden,221,6,0
7,201935,James Harden,-27,21,0
8,201935,James Harden,-119,235,0
9,201935,James Harden,-223,101,0
")
```

The numeric variables here come out as numeric, but we'll convert to integer (to match your data as closely as possible) below.

Extend the data (randomly) to the size of your full data set:

```
sfun <- function(x) sample(x,replace=TRUE,size=1456)
set.seed(101)
shots2 <- with(shots,
               data.frame(SHOT_MADE_FLAG=sfun(SHOT_MADE_FLAG),
                          LOC_X=as.integer(sfun(LOC_X)),
                          LOC_Y=as.integer(sfun(LOC_Y))))
```

Fit:

```
library(mgcv)
league_model_19 <- gam(SHOT_MADE_FLAG ~ ti(LOC_X) +
                           ti(LOC_Y) +
                           ti(LOC_X, LOC_Y),
                       data = shots2)
```

This works fine. You should try this code on your system and see if it works or not.

I also tried this with the data you provided above (333 rows) and it works fine.

So either (1) there's something weird about the remainder of your data that you haven't shown us, or (2) there's something weird about your R environment/package versions.

- For (1), it would be helpful if you can post your *full* data set somewhere. (It should be sufficient to post `shots[c('LOC_X','LOC_Y','SHOT_MADE_FLAG')]`, after checking that you still get the same issue with that subset of the data.  We might not need all of the rows to reproduce, but we definitely need more than we have already.)
- For (2), you could give us the results of `sessionInfo()` (or `devtools::session_info()`).  It would be helpful to start from a clean R session to minimize the number of additional packages you have loaded, and to minimize the possibility that you have weird function definitions masking the ones in the package.  (The results of `find("ti")`, `find("gam")` would also be useful; they should both be `package:mgcv` ...)